# Can we reuse a .dmp file(expdp) to perform import using data pump utility

Tags: oracle-11g, import, datapump

I'm an accidental DBA. We use Oracle 11g database. I had to do a database refresh in the test environment. I created a .dmp file using expdp command and performed an import using impdp command a week ago. I had to make some schema changes in test and then the department decided to revert to how it was before we made changes to the schema. The department wants me to perform impdp using the old .dmp file that I created a week ago. Can I re-use this file to do the import? Can the .dmp files be reused as many times as we can?

Comment: Of course it can.

Answer (score 3):

A DMP file is just a copy of the whole database contents. During the Import, it does not get modified, so you can use that file to "jump back" to the time when that dump file was created as often as you want.